# Selecting particular characters from the row of a matrix

Tags: r

Suppose I have a matrix with 4 rows and 1 columns :-

```
M[1,]<- s1 s2 s3 
M[2,]<- s2 s9 s1 s5 s6 s8 s3
M[3,]<- s4 s1 s7 s2 
M[4,]<- s2 s1 s3
```

Now I want to know how many rows have all the elements from the set `{s1,s2,s3}`. The rows might have other elements as well, but it should contain all of `s1`, `s2` and `s3` irrespective of order. Obviously the answer should be 3, as the first, second and fourth row satisfy this condition.
I know that I have to write a code something like this:-

```
j=0
for(i in 1:4)
{
if(M[i,] satisfies **condition**)
j=j+1
}
return(j)
```

I am not getting what should I write in place of the condition. I tried putting `if(M[i,]== "s1 s2 s3")`. But it gives answer 1. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split the `vector` into a `list` and use `%in%` with `all` to check if all the elements 's1', 's2', 's3' are found in the `list` element and get the `sum`

```
sum(sapply(strsplit(M[,1], "\\s+"), function(x) all(c("s1", "s2", "s3") %in% x)))
#[1] 3
```

---

Another option is to extract the values from the string, check the `lengths` equal to 3 (assuming that the values are not duplicated within a string)

```
library(stringr)
sum(lengths(str_extract_all(M,  "s1|s2|s3")) == 3)
#[1] 3
```

#### data

```
M <- structure(c("s1 s2 s3 ", "s2 s9 s1 s5 s6 s8 s3", "s4 s1 s7 s2", 
  "s2 s1 s3"), .Dim = c(4L, 1L))
```

Comment: But upon using it I am getting the output 4, whereas I need 3. I think it is giving true when at least one from the set is in the row. But I need "TRUE" when that row contains all the elements s1, s2, s3.

Comment: @user642080  I showed a reproducible example with the data and I am getting only 3

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun for helping me out. In particular the first technique is really nice.

Comment: Btw,I am trying to accept and upvote you, I don't know why I am unable to do so.

Comment: Okay. I see. Its okay. Words are much more stronger than Vote. Thanks a lot again...